# How to make a mixin with an undefined number of arguments that match the keys from a map and adding them as properties?

Tags: sass

Basically what I want to achieve is a mixin that I can specify which properties an element will have, by adding arguments in the mixin that match specific keys in a map.

**Example**

```
$map: (
    width: 100px,
    height: 100px,
    background: red;
    color: white;
);
```

The arguments from this mixin must match the keys in the $map.

```
@mixin specify-properties($props) {}
```

So, if I have something like this:

```
.element-1  {
    @include specify-properties(width, background);
}

.element-2 {
    @include specify-properties(width, height, color);
}
```

**It will output the key:value from $map**

```
.element-1 {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.element-2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours I figured it myself, not sure if this is the best way

```
$properties: (
    width: 100px,
    height: 100px,
    color: red,
    border: 2px
);

@mixin specify-properties($props...) {
        @each $prop in $props {
            $prop-value: map-get($properties, #{$prop});
            #{$prop}: #{$prop-value};
        }
}
```

Using the mixin:

```
.btn  {
@include specify-properties(color, width, height);
}
```

Outputs like I wanted:

```
.btn {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 //border won't appear since it's not specified in the argument.
}
```

If the arrgument in the mixin doesn't exist in the map it won't add it, just the rest that are specified and exists.

Pretty nice, I think.